# Возникает ошибка KeyError

Tags: python, словари

Я новичок в Python. Учусь по книге Майкла Доусона "Программируем на Python" .
В главе 5 последнее задание такое :

> Напишите программу «Кто твой папа?», в которой пользователь будет вводить имя человека, а программа
>   - называть отца этого человека. Чтобы было интереснее, можно «научить» программу родственным
>   отношениям среди литературных персонажей, исторических лиц и современных знаменитостей. Предоставьте
>   пользователю возможность добавлять, заменять и удалять пары «СЫН - отец».
>
> Доработайте программу «Кто твой папа?» так, чтобы можно было, введя имя человека, узнать, кто его дед.
>   Программа должна по-прежнему пользоваться одним словарем с парами «сын - отец». Подумайте, как
>   включить в этот словарь несколько поколений.

Я написал такую программу :

```
# Кто твой папа 2.0
family = {"Егор":["Алексей","Василий"],"Дмитрий":["Владимир","Пётр"]}
MENU = (
    """
    1 - Поиск отца человека по имени сына
    2 - Поиск деда человека по имени внука
    3 - Добавить пару сын - отец 
    4 - Изменить пару сын - отец 
    5 - Удалить пару сын - отец
    6 - Добавить деда человека в базу данных
    7 - Изменить пару внук - дед 
    8 - Удалить деда человека из базы данных 
    9 - Выход
     """
)
choice = 1 
while choice != 9 :
    print (MENU)
    choice = input ("Выберите цифру для действия : ")

    if choice == "1" :
        choice_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if choice_son in family :
            print(family[choice_son][0])
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "2" :
        choice_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if choice_son in family :
            print(family[choice_son][1])
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "3" :
        new_son = input ("Введите имя сына : ")
        if new_son not in family :
            family[new_son][0] = input ("Введите имя отца : ") # Ошибка

            print ("Пара успешно добавлена !")
        else :
            print ("Такой человек уже есть в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "4" :
        edit_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        edit_father = input ("Введите новое имя его отца : ") 
        family[edit_son][0] = edit_father 
        print ("Пара успешно изменена !")
    elif choice == "5" :
        del_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if del_son in family :
            del family[del_son] 
            print ("Пара успешно удалена !")
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "6" :
        choice_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if choice_son in family :
            new_granddad = input ("Введите имя деда для него : ")
            family[choice_son][1] = new_granddad 
            print ("Дед успешно добавлен !")
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "7" :
        choice_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if choice_son in family :
            edit_granddad = input ("Введите новое имя его деда : ")
            family[choice_son][1] = edit_granddad
            print ("Имя деда успешно изменено !")
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "8" :
        choice_son = input ("Введите имя человека : ")
        if choice_son in family :
            del family[choice_son][1]
            print ("Дед успешно удалён из базы данных !")
        else :
            print ("Такого человека нет в базе данных !")

    elif choice == "9" :
        print ("До свидания .")

    else : 
        print("Такого выбора нет !")

input ("Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти .")
```

Возникает ошибка `KeyError` , хотя я уверен что ключ `new_son` существует .

Comment: В коде целых 89 строк — возникает где и когда?

Comment: 38 строка , #Ошибка

Comment: `while choice != 9 :` - бесконечный цикл. Нужно исправить на `"9"`.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, для какого ввода возникает ошибка.

Comment: @ПавелДесятников но ведь перед этой строчкой написано `if new_son not in family :` — то есть это ваше `family[new_son][0]` будет выполняться ТОЛЬКО когда ключа `new_son` именно что НЕ существует — ошибка просто обязана возникать в таком случае

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интерпретатор, разбирая `family[new_son][0]`, пытается получить список по ключу new_son, чтобы в его нулевой элемент записать некоторое значение. То есть:

```
family_item = family[new_son] 
family_item[0] = input ("Введите имя отца : ")
```

Естественно, у него это не получается. Такого ключа нет. Более того, даже если бы вдруг получилось, появилась бы ошибка `list assignment index out of range`, так как нулевого элемента тоже не существует. Все эти действия надо производить явно

```
family_item = [] # создать массив
family[new_son] = family_item # записать его в словарь
family_item.append(input ("Введите имя отца : ")) # добавить в него значение
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
    if new_son not in family :
        family[new_son][0] = input ("Введите имя отца : ") # Ошибка
```

используйте

```
    if new_son not in family:
        family[new_son] = [input("Введите имя отца : ")]   # Уже нет ошибки
```

---

Обьяснение:

Вы хотите дла нового ключа (`new_son`) *определить его значение* - и вы хотите, чтобы этим значением был **список с одним элементом**.

Также вместо индекса `[0]` (для *затем не существующего списка*) просто примените квадратные скобки вокруг введенного имени отца.